# Converting a variable with a UTC time to a Seconds integer (Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a variable that has a UTC time tied with it,  example:

```
   offer_ends_at => Sun, 25 Nov 2012 07:59:59 UTC +00:00,
```

My goal is to create a new variable, and convert the Time to a seconds integer.   I tried with some methods like

```
   seconds = offer_ends_at.to_time.to_i
```

I end up getting a epoc time.  I'm after an actual integer that contains the amount of seconds left until the date happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you want " an actual integer that contains the amount of seconds left until the date happens.", then you can substract the timestamp you're getting, to the current timestamp, ie :

```
seconds = offer_ends_at.to_time.to_i - Time.now.to_i
```

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you don't need to put `to_i`, you can just substract the two times ([`Time#-`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-2D) method):

```
seconds = offer_ends_at.to_time - Time.now
```